# About composer installation

Tags: uninstall

I am new and sorry for this basic question. I runned

```
curl -sS https://getcomposer.org/installer -o composer-setup.php
```

accidentally on ubuntu 16.04

And I do not know any file downloaded or not. But if yes I want to remove them.

Any idea please ? Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This command will download the `installer` file from this link: https://getcomposer.org/installer and save it as `composer-setup.php` in the location where you run this command.

So if you just open a terminal from dash or with <kbd>ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>alt</kbd> + <kbd>t</kbd> hotkey, this file should probably be found in your home directory. You can just delete it from your file manager  or try the following command in your terminal:

`cd ~; rm -i composer-setup.php`